# I keep getting the same pid in my program after fork()

Tags: c++, multithreading, process

This is the code

```
pid_t pid;
srand(time(NULL));
for (int i=0; i < 2; i++)
{
    pid = fork();
    if (pid < 0)
    {
        std::cout<< "fork failed";
        return -1;
    }

    else if (pid == 0)
    {
        std::cout<< "Process "<< i+1 << " ID: " << pid <<std::endl;
        std::thread one (threadFunction, 0);
        std::thread two (threadFunction, 1);
        std::thread three (threadFunction, 2);
        one.join();
        two.join();
        three.join();
    }
    else
    {
        wait (NULL);
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

The loop is supposed to create two different processes but whenever I run this the output pid is always 0. Does this mean it the same process

Comment: When `if (pid == 0)` tests true, what did you think `<< pid` sent to stdout would produce? It's *still zero*.

Comment: `else if (pid == 0) { std::cout << pid;` I'm not sure what else you expect `pid` to be here since you're only running that logic when `pid` is 0. Perhaps you meant to swap the body of the `else if` with the body of the `else`?

Answer (score 1):

if pid == 0 your code is executing the child process. If pid is different than 0 your code execute the parent process

see section return value of the man
http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html

you can find out the real pid of the child with function getpid

http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/getpid.2.html

Comment: The pid will always be zero right. As a result the two different child processes pid will also be zero right

Comment: yes simple answer is the pid returned by fork will always be 0. To find out the real pid, use getpid function. I updated my answer

Comment: `fork()` will always return 0 *in the child process*. It will return the pid of the child in the parent process. Remember that `fork()` has *two* returns.

Comment: yes exactly, thats why alpha245 is able to see the Process pid 0 message printed. otherwise, without the wait call, the program may quit before it prints anything